# Database schema in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How can I add attributes like `null`, `default` or other database attributes directly from a model in Sails.js. I tried adding foreign key too, but it doesn't even affect the structure of my table.

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'users',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      null: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    point: {
      type: 'integer',
      defaultsTo: 0
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are asking about migration/upgrading the database? Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of ORM here. The thing is, sails.js doesn't "know" what type of database you are using. Is it a relational one, like mySQL, or is it a MongoDB, or maybe Redis. So, for example, the default value is set by sails in time of creating a record (if a value for that attribute is not provided), and not by some SQL statement, because the DB might not be SQL based. So there are limitations in Waterline, which is the default ORM of sails. If you want to use sails in a different way, you can replace Waterline or use a direct database adapter. But how can you do that is beyond the scope of this question.